# rng seeding and thread safety for __gnu_parallel::random_shuffle

Tags: c++, random, parallel-processing, libstdc++

I was hoping to use the parallel gnu extensions to accelerate a shuffle of an array, the shuffled array would then be used as a workload for an experiment involving sorting.  My two goals are speed in generating the workload,  and reproducibility of the experiment's results. A description of these gnu extensions is provided [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode_using.html#parallel_mode.using.specific).   I ended up confused about the interface:

From what I read, either I pass my own RNG, like the standard library allows, 
but then I assume I need to worry about thread safety.   The documentation here [(std::random_shuffle in cppreference)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) doesn't say much about thread safety requirements on the generator, neither does the gnu link above. So, I assume the worst.

Or,  If I don't pass my own RNG, then I assume the library takes care of it. I assume they do consider the multi-threading issues of the RNG in the implementation (though I couldn't find documentation affirming this either). But this leaves me with the problem: I wanted to control the seed to make sure the experiment I am doing is repeatable.  I found no documentation about controlling the seed of their default generator.

Both approaches have clear shortcomings.

A third option is to pass in a thread safe generator, for example, by using a lock on it. This seems silly, considering i'm trying to parallelize it.  It may still be better than purely sequential shuffle. I haven't tried.

Another option would be one based on thread local state, but I'm starting to get annoyed at having to think so much about how to use this library function.

Note: generating the workload in advance and remembering it is not an option, as I want to generate multiple GBs of data.

What would you do? Do you know of some other documentation I missed?

Comment: AFAICS, it only uses the RNG you give it to generate one number per thread at the beginning. In each thread, it then initializes its own RNG with these seeds. So you shouldn't need to give it a concurrent RNG. You can always file a documentation bug with gcc.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested the generator, the generated shuffle  does seem to be deterministic given the seed and the number of threads (which is consistent with your comment re implementation). If I change the number of threads, the generated workload changes. So, I guess it is better than nothing, but not fully reproducible.

Comment: Trying to make it reproducible with any number of threads would likely force the code to be more complicated and slower, and the priority in a parallel implementation is clearly speed.